# DispatchGroup and possible race condition?

Tags: swift

Will the following create a possible race condition?

```
let syncGroup = DispatchGroup()
var tempData: [Int]
for index in 1...10 {
      syncGroup.enter()
      // Alamofire is being called in the following. 
      // I am leaving out implementation, just to simplify.
      asyncTaskUsingAlamofire(completionHandler: { (data: [Data]) in
         // Possible race condition?
         // Should I use something like `sync()` and how?
         tempData.append(data)
         syncGroup.leave()
      })
}
syncGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
// We can go on, all data is added to tempData
}
```

I can see that swift has a `sync()` If and how would you solve this?

Comment: Yes, thanks - added and changed the question.

Comment: The problem is that you are not giving us enough information. A race condition can happen if the async tasks run on different threads/different queues. If they all run on the same queue, a race condition cannot happen. On which queue is the `completionHandler` called?

Comment: The async task is calling a Alamofire method, and I guess it is using queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that all completion handlers are called on the same queue. If they are not called on the same queue, they can be called simultaneously, creating a race condition.

If you are not sure whether the completion handler is called on a specific queue, you can simply insert an `.async` wrapper:

```
asyncTaskUsingAlamofire(completionHandler: { (data: [Data]) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        tempData.append(data)
        syncGroup.leave()
    }
}
```

However, Alamofire is always executing callbacks on the `main` queue, therefore no race conditions should happen and your solution is safe.

Answer (score 4):

### Serial Queue

Very similar to [Sulthan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43770037/1761687), I just usually use `custom serial queue` for this scenario

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
var results = [Int]()
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")

for _ in 1...10 {
    group.enter()
    asyncTaskUsingAlamofire { data in
        serialQueue.async {
            // Multiple instances of this block will be executed into a serial queue
            // So max 1 block at a time
            // This means results is accessed safely
            results.append(contentsOf: data)
            group.leave()
        }
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    print(results)
}
```

The `results` array is safely accessed because every instance of the block that mutate it

```
results.append(contentsOf: data)
group.leave()
```

is executed inside a Serial Queue.

```
serialQueue.async {
    results.append(contentsOf: data)
    group.leave()
}
```

In other words the 10 instances of the **block** are enqueued into `serialQueue` and executed **one at a time**.

This does guarantee a safe access of `results`.

Comment: Thanks - good point. Then you dont use 'main queue' until done.